# How to get the streaming wizard option in VLC - Windows?

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player, streaming

In MAC-OSX, the streaming wizard option is enabled by default in VLC. However, in windows, I dont' see that option. As I googled, I got to know that the VLC uses QT in Linux and Windows. Thus, it doesn't have those interfaces. Also, they say I need to enable the extended gui support to see the streaming wizard option. However, I couldn't locate any such option. I am using VLC on my WIndows 7 . The VLC version is 2.1.5 - Rincewind. I want to stream mutlicast UDP on my VLC. How to get the streaming wizard option in VLC - Windows?
If you scroll to the link here - you will see the screen shots of Streaming wizard in VLC - MAC OSX - http://www.tune2wizard.com/linux-arp-networking-devices-and-multicasting/

Comment: Media -> Stream?

Comment: No, stream doesn't have any option of multicasting. If you have MAC-OSX, then open the wizard option, you will see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, Media -> Stream is what you want.  The Mac OSX screenshots are similar to an earlier version of this UI in the QT interface, it was changed significantly in the 2.x releases.  Technically, you don't need to do anything special to do UDP multicast sending, just send it to a valid multicast address.  So, just go through the streaming wizard, select your source video, and when you get to the "Destination Setup" step, select "UDP (legacy)" and click "Add".

[image: Destination Setup]

After clicking "Add" you're taken to the UDP configuration screen, where you can configure the multicast address and port.

[image: UDP Configuration]

After that select your codecs and start streaming.

Comment: Not sure, whether it supports multicast udp packets or not. I wasn't successful in play a .ts file.

Comment: I can confirm that it does.  I just did using v2.1.5 on both the client and server.  The client network connection for the server I setup in the screenshots above should look something like this:  `udp://@239.255.1.1:7777`.  The `@` tells the client to join the multicast group.